# требования к веб серверу (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, администрирование, хостинг

Есть ASP.NET MVC сайт, суть сайта сводится к отображению пользователям их квитанций ЖКХ, по лицевому счету. На текущий момент хостится сайт на reg.ru. Руководство ставит задачу перенести сайт на локальный сервер. (который нужно конечно же купить). Тут у меня возникает проблема, а что же нужно из технических характеристик сервера (ядра, сколько,какие-частота, ОП память, HDD/SSD, ОС...), если планируется 5000-10000 одновременных подключений к серверу?

Comment: Если вас устраивают мощности текущего хостинга, то можно посмотреть на его ограничения и подобрать аналогичное железо.

Comment: мощность не устраивает